# Get route parameters Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Routing rules are:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    component: SkeletonComponent,
    children: [{
      path: "dictionary",
      component: DictionaryComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: ":dict/:code",
          component: VersionsComponent
        }]
}];
```

URL looks like:

http://localhost:4200/dictionary/Gender/5

Where `Gender` is parameter: `:dict` and `5` is parameter `:code`.

I tried to get parameters inside component `VersionsComponent`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['dict']);
    console.log(this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['code']);
}
```

I always get `undefined`

Comment: Can you try accessing it using `this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('dict');`?

Comment: It gives me null

Comment: Empty object: `ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}`

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue, as a stackblitz.

Comment: I have posted already here

Comment: What you have posted is far from being a complete example. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue, as a stackblitz.

Comment: Look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-rx3coy

Comment: Url is: https://angular-router-basic-example-rx3coy.stackblitz.io/dictionary/dict/code

Comment: You're using CatalogViewComponent twice in your stackblitz: once for the distionary route, which doesn't have any parameter, and one for the :dict/:code route. And its template doesn't have an router-outlet, so the child component can't be displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most effective way (works in all scenarios) is to subscribe to Activated Route. It'll work even when you don't switch between components, and only change the parametarised portions of the URL.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
  (params: Params) => {

    console.log(params.dict)

  }
)
```

If you don't subscribe to params, the code will only work when the component is loaded initially. After that, you need to leave the component for it to work again. By subscribing, you can load multiple resources without ever leaving the component.

Comment: Type of `params` should probably be [ParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) and should probably be `this.activatedRoute.paramMap` https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Comment: Is it correct import? import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

Comment: It gives me undefiuned: ` console.log(params.dict)`

Comment: And this gives empty object: `console.log(params.)`

Comment: I open page typing URL address, not using route link

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above go with paramMap. Please refer the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dadmby)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data.params)
    })
  }
```

Comment: it is still does not work for me, you have route differ

Comment: @Jony Can you please make a stackblitz project of the same that I can refer

Answer (score 0):

i think Your Routes configuration is wrong, should be like that:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SkeletonComponent
  },
  {
    path: "dictionary",
    component: DictionaryComponent,
    children: [{
      path: ":dict/:code",
      component: VersionsComponent
    }]
  }
];
```

**and make sure on DictionaryComponent your using `<router-outlet>`**

Answer (score 0):

The other answers that use 'subscribe' method are partially correct, but the reason you're still getting an error is that they're missing the 'get()' part, as per the Angular documentation:

https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Try this:

```js
    import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    myVar

    ngOnInit(): void { 
     this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe((data) => { 
          this.myVar = data.get('NameOfVariable')  // Put the name of whatever variable you're trying to get here
        }) 
        console.log(this.myVar)
     }
```

And it seems you've already received help on how to pass the data from the parent, but just to round off the answer, this is how I usually do it:

```html
 <button [routerLink]="['/myLink',dataVar]"> Click Here </button>
```